# Log to console from Javascript

Tags: ui4j

Is it possible to log to the java console?

I've tried to supply an object with a method on it to use for logging but nothing shows up in debug console.

Am I missing something?

```
window.setMember("mylog", new Console()); 

execute("mylog.log('11111111'))

public class Console { 
      public void log(Object ... objects) { 
           Logger...get..then..log(obj); 
      }
 }
```

Is there a better way to log to the Java console ?

This is not working.

Comment: What? java is to javascript as car is to carpet.

Comment: @Neal You need to get back to 2015. Plus, Rhino + EnvJS can do this quite well.

Comment: @Neal Thanks for the downvote. But I did figure out an answer to the question.

Comment: Can you post it then to help future visitors?

Comment: @Neal done. I posted an answer. This should perhaps get added to UI4J library.

Comment: Updated your question to remove the answer. And removed my DV (for now)

Comment: I had missed a method initially, i added it just now. putConsole(). I should down vote you for initially incorrectly downvoting me. You should apoligize :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, my code relies on a number of libraries and I am unable to push the solution to the UI4J repo.

It basically overrides the normal console.log and works similarly. **It intentionally avoids to JSON.stringify(object)** since circular dependencies can cause serious issues.

The code:

```
   import netscape.javascript.JSObject;
   import momomo.com.Opensource.sources.Functional.lambdas.version.interfaces.Lambda;


                  ....

                    try {
                            this.page = navigate( IO.toString(file) );
                            putConsole();
                    }
                    finally {
                            IO.remove(file);
                    }


             private void putConsole() {
                    // Note that we call log using the entire arguments ( array ) 
                    execute("console.log = function() {" +
                            put(CONSOLE) + ".log(arguments);" +
                    "};");
            }
    }

    private static final Console CONSOLE = new Console();
    public static final class Console {
            public void log(JSObject js) {

                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    iterate(js, (o) -> {
                            sb.append(o).append(" ");
                    });

                    $Log.info(Console.class, sb.toString());
            }
    }

    public static void iterate(JSObject js, Lambda.V1<Object> lambda) {
            iterate(js, lambda.R1());

    }
    public static void iterate(JSObject js, Lambda.R1<Boolean, Object> lambda) {
            if ( js != null ) {
                    Object member;

                    int i = 0;
                    while (true) {
                            member = js.getSlot(i);

                            if ( "undefined".equals(member) || Is.False( lambda.call(member) ) ) {
                                    return;
                            }                               

                            i++;
                    }

            }
    }
```

Outdated but useful Lambda.java reference:

https://github.com/momomo/Opensource/blob/master/src/momomo/com/Opensource/sources/Functional/lambdas/version/interfaces/Lambda.java

Note that put(CONSOLE) call above, basically calls execute("window").setMember("key", new Console()), so there is no magic there, although I have some other logic to achive the same result.